# scoreboard money show on bossbar

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using a bossbar to show the money value . This is the repeating command

```
execute store result bossbar money:bar value run scoreboard players get @p money
```

If playerA has 10 money and playerB has 20 money will playerB's bar show 20 and playerA's money bar show 10 ? And the money bars should be separate for
each player and I do not want a different bossbar for each player.

Comment: @FabianRöling that one's answer uses multiple bossbars i want to use one

Comment: That's the entire point of the question and answer, you can't show different values on the same bossbar to different players. So you need multiple bossbars if you want to display multiple values there, there's no way around it.